# FFmpeg - blur image according to blur map

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick

Is it possible with FFmpeg to blur a video according to blur map like this? Attached a sample.

Looking for a way to make specific parts of image blurred. Like ImageMagick's "compose blur", but for video.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not directly possible. Workaround is to use two filters.

```
ffmpeg -i video -filter_complex [0]split=2[full][blur];[blur]boxblur=OPTIONS[blur];[full][blur]overlay=format=auto -c:a copy output.
```